# display api data in nextjs through map function

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, axios, backend

i want to display data on the page but getting and error : data is not defined. please look on the code and help me

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import useLatestPosts from "../../hooks/useLatestPosts";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Head from "next/head";
export const Profile = ({ po }) => {
const { latestPosts } = useLatestPosts();
const router = useRouter()
const username = router.query
const fetchUserData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/profile/${username.slug1}`)
    console.log("data", data);

}
useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserData()
}, [])

return (
    <>
        <Head>
            <title>{username.slug1}</title>
        </Head>
        <div>
            <h1>Profile Name</h1>
            {data.map((user)=>(
              <li key={user.id}>
               <h1>{user.name}</h1>
              </li>
            ))
           }

        </div>

    </>
);
};

export default Profile;
```

data is displaying in console in the object form when i comment jsx code but then i un-comment jsx code it again shows me "data is not defined"

Comment: data is not accesible from your component. You should create a state, then fill the state with data from the axios request, and render your component using that state

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the `data` variable inside your JSX, but it is not defined anywhere in your component. You can define it in your component's state:

```
...
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const fetchUserData = async () => {
  const { data } = await ...
  setData(data);
}
...
```

Comment: yes i defined same like this and didn't get yet

Comment: const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/profile/${username.slug1}`)
        setUsers(data)
        console.log(data)

    }

Comment: {users.length > 0 ? (
                    <div>
                        {users.map((profile) => (
                            <div>
                                <h2>{profile.user.name}</h2>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <p className="loading">Loading... </p>
                )}

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const fetchUserData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/profile/${username.slug1}`)
    setUsers(data)
    console.log(data)

}
useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserData()
}, [])

return (
    <>
        <Head>
            <title>{username.slug1}</title>
        </Head>
        <div>
            <h1>Profile</h1>
            {users.length > 0 ? (
                <div>
                    {users.map((profile) => (
                        <div>
                            <h2>{profile.user.name}</h2>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            ) : (
                <p className="loading">Loading... </p>
            )}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).